En mi clase CurriculumVitae no aparecen la lista de WorkExperience
Hola estoy haciendo una pequeña aplicacion en spring boot para un curriculum esta es mi clase
CurriculumVitae donde se puede el problema de obtener listas vacías en la respuesta JSON de la API
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "curriculum_vitae")
public class CurriculumVitae {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String lastName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "curriculumVitae", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<WorkExperience> workExperiences;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "curriculumVitae", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<LevelEducation> levelEducations;

}

En mi clase Curriculum cree una lista WorkExperience, cuando hago el test de mi api en postman  mi json sale  una lista de objetos vacio
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Jean Dupont",
        "lastName": "Dupont",
        "workExperiences": [],
        "levelEducations": []
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Jean Dupont",
        "lastName": "Dupont",
        "workExperiences": [],
        "levelEducations": []
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Jean Dupont",
        "lastName": "Dupont",
        "workExperiences": [],
        "levelEducations": []
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Jean Dupont",
        "lastName": "Dupont",
        "workExperiences": [],
        "levelEducations": []
    }
] 

alguien tiene una idea del problema, por ahora no encuentro la solucion coloco parte de codigo de mis clases
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "work_experience")
@JsonIgnoreProperties("curriculumVitae")
public class WorkExperience {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String company;

    private String position;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date startDate;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date endDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "curriculum_id")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private CurriculumVitae curriculumVitae;

}

Mis DTO para las dos clases
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CurriculumVitaeDTO implements Serializable {

    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8732529708250756609L;

    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String lastName;

    private List<WorkExperience> workExperiences;

    private List<LevelEducationDTO> levelEducations;

    }

@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class WorkExperienceDTO {

    private Long id;

    private String company;

    private String position;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date startDate;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date endDate;
}


Mis mappers estoy utilizando mapstruct para hacer el mapeo
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface CurriculumVitaeMapper {

    CurriculumVitaeMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(CurriculumVitaeMapper.class);


    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(source = "id", target = "id"),
            @Mapping(source = "workExperiences", target = "workExperiences"),
            @Mapping(source = "levelEducations", target = "levelEducations")
    })
    CurriculumVitaeDTO toDto(CurriculumVitae curriculumVitae);

    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(source = "id", target = "id"),
            @Mapping(source = "workExperiences", target = "workExperiences"),
            @Mapping(source = "levelEducations", target = "levelEducations")
    })
    CurriculumVitae toEntityCurriculumVitae(CurriculumVitaeDTO curriculumVitae);
}


@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface WorkExperienceMapper {

    WorkExperienceMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(WorkExperienceMapper.class);

    @Mapping(source = "id", target = "id")
    WorkExperienceDTO toWorkExperienceDTO(WorkExperience workExperience);

    @Mapping(source = "id", target = "id")
    WorkExperience toEntityWorkExperience(WorkExperienceDTO workExperienceDTO);
}

Mis servicios de las clases
@Service
public class CurriculumVitaeServiceImpl implements CurriculumVitaeServiceInter {

    private final CurriculumVitaeRepository curriculumVitaeRepository;

    private final CurriculumVitaeMapper curriculumVitaeMapper;

    public CurriculumVitaeServiceImpl(CurriculumVitaeRepository curriculumVitaeRepository, CurriculumVitaeMapper curriculumVitaeMapper) {
        this.curriculumVitaeRepository = curriculumVitaeRepository;
        this.curriculumVitaeMapper = curriculumVitaeMapper;
    }


    @Override
    public List<CurriculumVitaeDTO> getAllCurriculumVitaes() {
        return curriculumVitaeRepository.findAll()
                .stream()
                .map(curriculumVitaeMapper::toDto)
                .toList();
    }

    @Override
    public CurriculumVitaeDTO createCurriculumVitae(CurriculumVitaeDTO curriculumVitaeDTO) {

        if (curriculumVitaeDTO.getName() == null || curriculumVitaeDTO.getName().isEmpty()) {
            throw new BadRequestException("The name of Curriculum Vitae  is mandatory");
        }

        var newCurriculumVitae = curriculumVitaeMapper.toEntityCurriculumVitae(curriculumVitaeDTO);
        newCurriculumVitae = curriculumVitaeRepository.save(newCurriculumVitae);

        return curriculumVitaeMapper.toDto(newCurriculumVitae);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<CurriculumVitaeDTO> getCurriculumVitaeById(Long id) {
        if (!curriculumVitaeRepository.existsById(id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException("Curriculum Vitae with id " + id + " doesn't exist");
        }
        return curriculumVitaeRepository.findById(id).map(curriculumVitaeMapper::toDto);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteCurriculumVitae(Long id) {

        if (!curriculumVitaeRepository.existsById(id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException("Curriculum Vitae with id " + id + " not found");
        }
        curriculumVitaeRepository.deleteById(id);
    }


@Service
public class WorkExperienceServiceImpl implements WorkExperienceServiceInter {


    private final WorkExperienceRepository workExperienceRepository;

    private final WorkExperienceMapper workExperienceMapper;

    public WorkExperienceServiceImpl(WorkExperienceRepository workExperienceRepository, WorkExperienceMapper workExperienceMapper) {
        this.workExperienceRepository = workExperienceRepository;
        this.workExperienceMapper = workExperienceMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public List<WorkExperienceDTO> getAllWorkExperience() {
        return workExperienceRepository.findAll()
                .stream()
                .map(workExperienceMapper::toWorkExperienceDTO)
                .toList();
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<WorkExperienceDTO> getWorkExperienceById(Long id) {
        if (!workExperienceRepository.existsById(id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException("Work experience with id " + id + " doesn't exist");
        }
        return workExperienceRepository.findById(id).map(workExperienceMapper::toWorkExperienceDTO);
    }

    @Override
    public WorkExperienceDTO createWorkExperience(WorkExperienceDTO workExperienceDTO) {
        WorkExperience newExperienceDTO = workExperienceMapper.toEntityWorkExperience(workExperienceDTO);
        newExperienceDTO = workExperienceRepository.save(newExperienceDTO);

        if (workExperienceDTO.getCompany().isEmpty()) {
            throw new BadRequestException(" The name of Company is mandatory ");
        }

        return workExperienceMapper.toWorkExperienceDTO(newExperienceDTO);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteWorkExperience(Long id) {
        if (!workExperienceRepository.existsById(id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException("Work experience with id " + id + " not found");
        }
        workExperienceRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}


Mis controller
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class CurriculumVitaeController {

    private final CurriculumVitaeServiceInter curriculumVitaeServiceInter;

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CurriculumVitaeController.class);


    public CurriculumVitaeController(CurriculumVitaeServiceInter curriculumVitaeServiceInter) {
        this.curriculumVitaeServiceInter = curriculumVitaeServiceInter;
    }


    @GetMapping(value = "/curriculumVitaes", produces = MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_GRAPHQL_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<List<CurriculumVitaeDTO>> getAllCurriculumVitaes() {

        List<CurriculumVitaeDTO> curriculumVitaeDTOList = curriculumVitaeServiceInter.getAllCurriculumVitaes();

        if (curriculumVitaeDTOList != null && curriculumVitaeDTOList.isEmpty()) {
            return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
        }
        logger.info("Find CurriculumVitae service finished");
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(curriculumVitaeDTOList);

    }


    @PostMapping(value = "/curriculumVitae", produces = MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<CurriculumVitaeDTO> createCurriculum(@Valid @RequestBody CurriculumVitaeDTO curriculumVitaeDTO) {
        if (curriculumVitaeDTO.getName() == null || curriculumVitaeDTO.getName().trim().isEmpty()) {
            throw new BusinessException("Curriculum Vitae is required", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        CurriculumVitaeDTO newCurriculumDTO = curriculumVitaeServiceInter.createCurriculumVitae(curriculumVitaeDTO);

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(newCurriculumDTO);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/curriculumVitae/{id}", produces = MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Optional<CurriculumVitaeDTO>> getCurriculumVitae(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Optional<CurriculumVitaeDTO> newCurriculumVitae = curriculumVitaeServiceInter.getCurriculumVitaeById(id);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(newCurriculumVitae);
    }

    @DeleteMapping(value = "/curriculumVitae/{id}", produces = MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> deleteCurriculumVitae(@PathVariable Long id) {
        curriculumVitaeServiceInter.deleteCurriculumVitae(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body("Curriculum Vitae is deleted");

    }

    @PutMapping(value = "/curriculumVitae/update", produces = MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<CurriculumVitaeDTO> updateCurriculumVitae(@Valid @RequestBody CurriculumVitaeDTO curriculumVitaeDTO) {
        if (curriculumVitaeDTO.getId() == null) {
            throw new BusinessException("Curriculum Vitae is required", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        CurriculumVitaeDTO updateCurriculumVitae = curriculumVitaeServiceInter.createCurriculumVitae(curriculumVitaeDTO);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(updateCurriculumVitae);
    }

}


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class WorkExperienceController {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WorkExperienceController.class);

    private final WorkExperienceServiceInter workExperienceServiceInter;

    public WorkExperienceController(WorkExperienceServiceInter workExperienceServiceInter) {
        this.workExperienceServiceInter = workExperienceServiceInter;
    }


    @GetMapping(value = "/workExperiences", produces = MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<List<WorkExperienceDTO>> getAllWorkExperience() {
        List<WorkExperienceDTO> workExperienceDTOList = workExperienceServiceInter.getAllWorkExperience();

        if (workExperienceDTOList.isEmpty()) {
            return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(workExperienceDTOList);
    }


    @PostMapping(value = "/workExperience", produces = MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<WorkExperienceDTO> createWorkExperience(@RequestBody WorkExperienceDTO workExperienceDTO) {
        if (workExperienceDTO.getCompany() == null || workExperienceDTO.getCompany().trim().isEmpty()) {
            throw new BadRequestException("Company name cannot be empty");
        }

        WorkExperienceDTO newWorkExperience = workExperienceServiceInter.createWorkExperience(workExperienceDTO);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(newWorkExperience);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/workExperience/{id}", produces = MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Optional<WorkExperienceDTO>> getWorkExperienceById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Optional<WorkExperienceDTO> workExperienceDTO = workExperienceServiceInter.getWorkExperienceById(id);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(workExperienceDTO);
    }

    @DeleteMapping(value = "/workExperience/{id}", produces = MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> deleteWorkExperience(@PathVariable Long id) {
        workExperienceServiceInter.deleteWorkExperience(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Work Experience deleted");
    }

    @PutMapping(value = "/update")
    public ResponseEntity<WorkExperienceDTO> updateWorkExperience(@Valid @RequestBody WorkExperienceDTO workExperienceDTO) {
        if (workExperienceDTO.getId() == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(null);
        }

        var updateWorkExperienceDTO = workExperienceServiceInter.createWorkExperience(workExperienceDTO);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(updateWorkExperienceDTO);
    }

}



Gracias por su ayuda
